# Guess Number Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having trouble with this program. It is suposed to generate a random whole number between 1 and 1000 but it will generate something like 627.68969869867986985747640967487598563876586805465097080967576587609787587658976098

```
 from random import *
 def main():

    numGuess = input ("guess your number")
    ranNum = randint(8, 100000)
    while ranNum <> numGuess:
        print numGuess
        numGuess = input ("guess your number")
        print numGuess
        ranNum = randint(0,1000)
        if numGuess > ranNum :
            print("ugg, your number is too big")
        else:
            print("whoops, your number is too small")
        if numGuess == ranNum :
            print("YAHOO, YOU GOT IT RIGHT!!!!!!!!")
   main()
```

could someone tell me why this is not working (it was ran in a python 2.7 editor)
also, The first time you enter your number it does not tell you if you should guess higher or lower.

Comment: How are you determining that it generates this strange looking number? I have a hard time believing that `randint` is giving you something that is not an integer. Also, can you format your code properly? I somehow doubt your main is infinitely recursive, for example.

Comment: Well you do ask the user two times before you ever print if its higher or lower.

Comment: The code you've posted has many errors, but not one like you describe.

Comment: You have a lot of errors here. Try to really think about what you're doing. For example, you shouldn't be asking the user for two guesses before ever saying if its too big or too small.

Comment: `<>` is deprecated. Better to use `!=` instead.

Answer (score 0):

A few things.  You generally shouldn't use * in your Python imports (`from module import *`).  If you're only using one function from the module, it is much safer and your code will be more easily understood if you use `from random import randint`.

You are reassigning your ranNum after the first guess.  Your first guess could change to a correct answer once ranNum has been reassigned to a new value.

Also, your description says you are looking to generate a random number between 1 and 1000, but your first assignment of ranNum is `ranNum == randint(8, 10000)` and that will generate a random int between 8 and 10000.

My suggestion is to remove the name assignments that are outside of the loop and change your while condition to `while True:` then in your `if numGuess == ranNum:` logic, add a `break` statement to break the loop inside main().

As for your question, I don't believe you're getting a long result such as the one you provided by using randint().  Is there a part of your code you have left out?

Answer (score 0):

A few things are either redundant or done wrong, the following is a modification of your solution with a few changes:

```
from random import *
def main():

    numGuess = -1
    ranNum = randint(1, 1000)
    while ranNum <> numGuess:        
        numGuess = input ("guess your number")
        print numGuess        
        if numGuess > ranNum :
            print("ugg, your number is too big")
        elif numGuess < ranNum:
            print("whoops, your number is too small")
        else:
            print("YAHOO, YOU GOT IT RIGHT!!!!!!!!")
main()
```

- you ask for the user's input twice in the beginning because of the redundant call before the while loop
- The call to `ranNum = randint(8, 100000)` - not needed
- You want to do `ranNum = randint(0,1000)` only once, before you start looping
- The if/else/if mechanism - can be improved (see above)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, just corrected in your code..

```
from random import *
def main():

    numGuess = 1
    ranNum = 10
    while ranNum <> numGuess:
        ranNum = randint(1,1000)
        numGuess = input ("guess your number")
        #print ranNum, "random"
        if numGuess > ranNum :
            print("ugg, your number is too big")
        elif numGuess < ranNum:
            print("whoops, your number is too small")
        else:
            print("YAHOO, YOU GOT IT RIGHT!!!!!!!!")
main()
```